# Error creating a Oracle NoSQL table with ENUM fields

Tags: oracle-nosql

I have the following error when trying to create this table :
IllegalArgumentException: Error: at (1, 88) Missing closing ')', at line 1:88

```
Create table TEST (
id String,
fileType ENUM (DOCUMENT,VIDEO),
status ENUM (IN_PROGRESS,PARTIAL_SUCCESS,SUCCEEDED,FAILED,NULL),
primary key (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent a little time to understand what I was doing wrong, the error message is not clear.

Literal "null" is a reserved word in the query language so it is not supported in that location.

```
status ENUM (IN_PROGRESS,PARTIAL_SUCCESS,SUCCEEDED,FAILED,NULL),
```

By the way, We can insert data with null values for the ENUM fields.So, I just create the same table but without including the value NULL

```
Create table TEST (
id String,
fileType ENUM (DOCUMENT,VIDEO),
status ENUM (IN_PROGRESS,PARTIAL_SUCCESS,SUCCEEDED,FAILED),
primary key (id)
)
```